# How to reach a particular IP address from netmask /30 to netmask /28

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm setting up a new Amazon VPC through the console but it's restricted to between a /16 netmask and /28 netmask.

From the other side, a client expects to get an EC2 instance at their end of the tunnel from an internal network with a netmask  of /30.

So then, how can I create a VPC which is capable of hosting EC2 instances on the CIDR block 172.30.228.184/30 ? How should that subnet be configured in order to communicate with the /30 block?

Comment: `From the other side, a client expects to get an EC2 instance at their end of the tunnel from an internal network with a netmask of /30` - why? As long as you don't have bad (overlaping) ip network design, it should not really matter and even then I am quite sure that you can find some unused private range.

Answer (score 0):

AWS preserve 4 IPs to use for there purpose on each subnet, so you cannot create /30 subnet. See [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html).

> The first four IP addresses and the last IP address in each subnet CIDR block are not available for you to use, and cannot be assigned to an instance. For example, in a subnet with CIDR block 10.0.0.0/24, the following five IP addresses are reserved:
>
> 10.0.0.0: Network address.
>
> 10.0.0.1: Reserved by AWS for the VPC router.
>
> 10.0.0.2: Reserved by AWS. The IP address of the DNS server is always the base of the VPC network range plus two; however, we also reserve the base of each subnet range plus two. For VPCs with multiple CIDR blocks, the IP address of the DNS server is located in the primary CIDR. For more information, see Amazon DNS Server.
>
> 10.0.0.3: Reserved by AWS for future use.
>
> 10.0.0.255: Network broadcast address. We do not support broadcast in a VPC, therefore we reserve this address.